# SOAP response against XSD getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml, xsd, soapui

I'm trying to validate soap response against xsd schema file using java. but while running I'm getting below exception

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xh:ResponseHeader' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Problem here is. In my XSD file , I'm calling some other files using relative path. I doubt my code is not able to read those file. but same code is working in SOAPUI.

## XSD;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://response.header.emtservice.acxsys.com/ws/schema/3/4/1" schemaLocation="../ResponseHeader.xsd" /> 
<xsd:import namespace="http://common.emtservice.acxsys.com/ws/schema/3/4/1" schemaLocation="../Elements.xsd" />

<xsd:element name="SendTransferResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="responseHeader" type="xh:ResponseHeader" />
            <xsd:element name="transferReferenceNumber" type="t:transferreferencenumber" />
            <xsd:element name="fraudCheckResult" type="t:FraudCheckResult" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

## Java Code is

```
          SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Response.xsd"));  

          Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(fileInputStream));  


          Validator val = schema.newValidator(); 

          val.validate(new StreamSource(soapResponse));
```

Thanks

Comment: never reference a folder back by .. , create a folder name xsds and put all of xsd files in the same directory so that you could easily reference them as schemaLocation="ResponseHeader.xsd"

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine

```
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("Response.xsd"));

    Validator val = schema.newValidator();

    // create a source from a string
    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(response));

    // check input
    boolean isValid = true;
    try {

        val.validate(source);
    } catch (SAXException e) {

        System.err.println(e);
        System.err.println("Not valid");
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;

}
```